# no c++ printf output after grep pipe

Tags: c++, grep, printf

My c++ program outputs numbers in a loop ( printf("%d\n",var) ).

```
$ sudo ./cc1101
1904548736
1904548736
1904548736
1904548736
1904548736
```

But when i apply grep filter there is no output anymore:

```
$ sudo ./cc1101|grep 1904548736
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `printf` in a C++ program?

Comment: Why are you running your program with sudo? Where is the sourcecode? If you want an accurate answer, you need to provide an accurate error description first.

Comment: The type safety employed by the C++ model of writing to the console.

Comment: @user947668: Is grep aliased? Check with `type grep`.